# If $A^{2n}=I$, then $A^n=\pm I$ where $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$be a matrix. Then, if we have $A^{2n}=I$, can we say that $A^n=\pm I$?

I think yes, because the annihilating polynomial is $x^{2n}-1$. Therefore the characteristic polynomial should be one of $x^n-1$ or $x^n+1$. Thus, since the matrix consists of real numbers, therefore, the matrix $A^n=\pm I$. Am I wrong?Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n=3,\ A=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1),\ A^3=A\ne\pm I,\ A^6=I$.

Comment: Worth noting that $p(x) = x^6 - 1$ does annihilate this matrix, and the *minimal* polynomial must divide $p$...but the minimal polynomial for this matrix is $(x-1)(x+1)$, which is neither $x^3 -1$ nor $x^3 + 1$ (one of which has $x-1$ as a factor, and the other of which has $x+1$ as a factor).

Comment: @JohnHughes by the way, what is the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @JohnHughes got it. It is $(x-1)(x+1)^2$

Comment: If you are unsure of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$ in this answer, I think you need to review the definition of characteristic polynomial in terms of determinants.